# How to define message bus contracts with OpenApi

Tags: openapi

At my current company, we extensively use OpenAPI and [Stoplight Studio](https://stoplight.io/studio/) to define API contracts.

We are now starting to use message bus concepts, and would like to keep using Stoplight Studio for message definitions too.

I can't see anywhere on the Stoplight Studio website that specifically mentions message bus, or messaging.

Is this scenario supported by OpenAPI?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about "Spotlight Studio" specifically, but [Async API](https://www.asyncapi.com/docs/tutorials/getting-started/coming-from-openapi) was designed to bring OpenAPI style contract definitions to Event Driven Architectures.